# ng-animate retains duplicated DOM element on Chrome 49.x

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate

I have problem since the latest Chrome browser was released. 
I'm using angular 1.2.0 app with ng-animate included.

In my index file I have container element like

```
<div id="container" ng-class="{container:$root.container}" ng-view ng-cloak ></div>
```

Since the latest Chrome release I have the issue, when the transitions are finished the app view ends with 2 container with vertical/horizontal scroll. They become three, four and so on in the DOM after each transition.

The inline css snapshot in Chrome, when I have only two DOM containers is:

```
class="ng-scope container ng-animate ng-leave ng-animate-start ng-animate-active ng-leave-active"
```

for the first one and

```
class="ng-scope container ng-animate ng-enter ng-animate-start ng-animate-active ng-enter-active"
```

for the second.

The problem is the this is only on Chrome 49. On other browsers it is acting as expected. On firefox for example (same applies for safari) looking at the DOM on the on each transition I can see that the ng-animate creates second element and then removes it. It ends only with

```
class="ng-scope container"
```

Anyone with same problem ? I can't see any decent solution for now. I don;t want to add watchers in some parent controller or any similar ugly patch. 
Thanks in advance guys!